# Why does my express-session variable return 'undefined' on a different route?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I have a simple login form which sets a session after the login is successful

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  // TODO: Hash password
  if (username === 'admin' && password === 'test') {
    req.session.user = username;
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  } else {
    // TODO: Validation
  }
});
```

Before this I set the middleware:

```
router.use(sessions({
  secret: 'supersecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    sameSite: true,
    secure: true,
    expires: false
  }
}));
```

After the `session.user` is set, the router redirects to `/dashboard`, but when I try to `console.log(req.session.user)`, it returns `undefined`, though `req.session` doesn't.

```
router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session.user);

  if (req.session.user) {
    Product.find({}, (e, products) => {
      if (e) console.error(e);

      res.render('dashboard', {
        products: products
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? It might also be worth noting that it does return the correct value inside `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it didn't work because I set `cookie.secure` to `true`. But this only works on https sites, though I'm testing this on my localhost. So the solution is as simple as setting `secure: false`.